# neo4j indexes getting polluted with extra data from other nodes

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j and the indexes are not working as I expected. I have a `word` node and an `isbn` node. I created two indexes - one called `words` and one called `isbns`. But I am finding somehow the `words` index is getting `isbn` nodes.

Hence word <--- WROTE ---- ISBN

I do not really understand how the indexes work in Neo4j and I would like any information someone has (eg a link).

I have a lot of code but it is all fairly complex but if someone has an exact question, I can copy some specific code.

Is there any way to actually list just the index itself? e.g. Can I browse my words index and see exactly what it contains? I tried a query but I need to specify a node I think.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of neo4j are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Indexing is documented at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing.html. Depending on your use case consider usage of auto indexes.